# How to determine the size of a file from the strings

Tags: c, string, text, filesize

I have a test file called text.txt. Its contents:

```
as
bq

df
```

But the file size of text.txt is 12 bytes. Why is it 12 bytes? The first line has 3 bytes `as\n`. The second line has 3 bytes `bq\n`. The third line is 1 byte `\n`. The fourth line is 3 bytes `dfEOF`.

`3 + 3 + 1 + 3 = 10 bytes`

But when I check the size of the file, it says 12 bytes. If I just have a single character in my txt. It says 1 byte. So I am confused as to how I get 12 bytes

A GIF of my one notepad++ pressing the right arrow key. Showing you there is no spaces whitespace:
https://gyazo.com/82717bd0e339188adae3d72dc243ba37

My hex: `61 73 0d 0a 62 71 0d 0a 0d 0a 64 66`

Comment: @tod I have checked for spaces and ensured there is no spaces. I even did a `CTRL+F` to find spaces. Try this yourself on your computer

Comment: Examine the file contents with a hex editor/viewer, and you will have your answer.  Most likely the line you think is empty is actually not.  Or there are additional whitespace characters, or you somehow ended up with a byte-order mark on the file.

Comment: Are you sure your `EOLN` characters are `\n` and not `\r\n`?  There's (probably) no `EOF` marker either.  That leaves you 3 bytes short, and there's 3 lines with an `EOLN`.  Do you have access to a binary editor?

Comment: @Kingsley I only have notepad++

Comment: @Kingsley @paddy I have updated my post with the hex values. I see that `0a` is the value messing my calculation up. What is `0a`?

Comment: Windows uses 2 characters for line endings. So perhaps it's not `as\n` , but `as\r\n` instead. (Note that if you read the file in text mode in your code, the stdio functions will remove the \r before passing the content to your code)

Comment: `0d0a` - these are Windows `EOLN`s ~ `\r\n`, so your end-of-line marker is 2-bytes.  UNIX uses `\n`

Comment: @Kingsley i see in my hex, there is no EOF marker. Why isn't there an EOF marker at the end?

Comment: There is no such thing as a "EOF" character or marker. Good reading: https://latedev.wordpress.com/2012/12/04/all-about-eof/

Comment: @Kiwa - EOT markers are a bit of a hang-over from teletype days.  Text editors these days do not add them to files.  However IF there is one in your file, and you open it in text-read mode `fopen(..., "rt")` it can still raise EOF to your program.  Or at least it did once for me on C89 when I had a ^Z in a file.  EDIT: not EOF, but EOT.

Comment: Here's some interesting reading about EOF/EOT.  https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/315151/whats-the-last-character-in-a-file  - TL;DR - There *were* EOF bytes on some systems.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Given the contents are

```
My hex: 61 73 0d 0a 62 71 0d 0a 0d 0a 64 66
```

Your 12 bytes are

```
61 73  <- this is 'as'
0d 0a  <- CR-LF newline characters
62 71  <- this is 'bq'
0d 0a  <- CR-LF
0d 0a  <- CR-LF for empty line
64 66  <- `df`
```

That's 12.  Note that your last line does not have a CR-LF pair.

Comment: 4 + 4 + 2 + 2 does in fact equal 12, i think this guys on to something here!

Comment: Maybe you could add what CR and LF stand for.